# Resize image while uploading to amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to resize image to 150 x 150 px and then upload it to Amazon S3

Following is the code:

```
               $image = $_FILES["userImage"]["name"];

                $fileTempName = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];

                $new_width  = 150;
                $new_height = 150;

                $image_p    = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

                $image      = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fileTempName));
                imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));

                $newFielName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "tempfilename"); 
                imagepng($image_p, $newFielName, 9); 

                 $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

                //move the file
                if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "urimages", $newFielName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {

                    $image_link = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/urimages/' . $newFielName . '';

                    $this->Product->saveField('image', $image_link);

                }
```

Following is the link which i receive upon uploading  : https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/urimages/C:/Users/LS/AppData/Local/Temp/9102.tmp

Could be you please help me debug the code

Comment: You have not mentioned any error messages or any problems that you are having with this code - what exactly needs to be debugged? Please provide the relevant information on what issues you are facing so that the community can help you.

Comment: @Lix upon uploading i get the url https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/urimages/C:/Users/LS/AppData/Local/Temp/9102.tmp .it shows corrupt image

Comment: please look at the text that is showed from the link you posted. It is not a corrupted image.

Comment: Rather than resizing the image, you could use a Image Resizing service that can do it for you, when serving the images to your users. See:
 [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) and [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *i think issue in path. Please create folder on s3 and make a valid
>   path according to that folder*
>
> https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/urimages/C:/Users/LS/AppData/Local/Temp/9102.tmp

[Example :- Resampling an image proportionally](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Comment: It's pretty easy to just copy paste an example from the documentation, isn't it?

Comment: The least you could do would be to include a [link back to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) so that people can read up a little more on the topic.

Comment: I realize that you are just trying to help - but what you have done here is just thrown the documentation at the person asking a question.

Comment: @Lix Sorry for that i will add documentation link